# Object mapper cannot serialize Reference of Object class

Tags: java, jackson

I have a Notification class:

```
package com.code2hack.notification;

public class Notification {
    private Object message;
    private NotificationType type;

    public static Notification create(NotificationType type,Object message){
        return new Notification(message,type);
    }

    public Notification(){

    }
    public Notification(Object message,NotificationType type){
        this.message = message;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Notification{" +
                "message=" + message +
                ", type=" + type +
                '}';
    }

    public <T> T getMessage(Class<T> type){
        return (T)this.message;
    }
    public NotificationType getType(){
        return this.type;
    }
    public void setType(NotificationType type){
        this.type = type;
    }
    public void setMessage(Object message){
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

when I use `ObjectMapper` from spring it does not convert message field to Json.

```
public static void main(String ...str){
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(Notification.create(NotificationType.NEW_SCHEDULE,"NEW Schedule"));
   System.out.println(json);
}
```

This is not converting message property in Notification to json.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: You have no getter for the message field. That's why Jackson doesn't serialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not using `getters` in your Class the `jackson` wont print it unless you will specify to him that the `message` is part of the json.

```
@JsonProperty
private Object message;
```

That should do the work